# How to center an item that has a variable width?

Tags: css

I'd like to center a submit button. How do I accomplish this? I dont know the width of the button, it may be flexible based on the text inside it. I'm trying not to use float and set the margin auto on it because that will require a width.

```
<input type="submit" value="may vary" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the width is variable, your best bet is to use the text-align property of the container. If that would effect other sibling elements in an undesirable way, consider wrapping the input in a div.

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <input type="submit" value="may vary" />
</div>
```

**NOTE:** The inline CSS above is just an example, feel free to create a css rule for the div.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the often overlooked, simple `text-align` solution. It seems a lot of people go crazy trying to center things, usually as a result of float abuse.